# How to crop a Bitmap with a minimum usage of memory?

Tags: android, bitmap, crop, out-of-memory

In my app I'm loading plenty of images from the web. That's working fine so far:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess( byte[] response )
{
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( response, 0, response.length, options );

    ...
}
```

But in fact it would be nice to use only an extract of the image during the application process. So I tried something like this:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess( byte[] response )
{
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( response, 0, response.length, options );
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap( source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight() - 30 );
    source.recycle();
    source = null;

    ...
}
```

But my app keeps crashing after loading a few dozens of images (OutOfMemoryException). So (I guess) I have two opportunities to get rid off the 30 pixels of height (it's actually a credit information, but don't worry, I'm not stealing, it's okay if I hide it):

- Crop & save the image with less memory usage, or
- Manipulate the ImageView to hide the bottom of the image (height may vary due to scaling)

But I need some advice for these techniques.

Comment: Wait a second, wouldn't what you're already doing actually crop the image?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    private Bitmap trimImage(Bitmap source)
    {
        int trimY = 20; //Whatever you want to cut off the top
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), source.getConfig());
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmOverlay);

        //Source and destination Rects based on sprite animation.
        Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, trimY, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight()); 
        Rect dstRect = new Rect(0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        c.drawBitmap(manual1, srcRect, dstRect, null);

        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

This hasn't been tested, but something like this might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to saving memory with bitmaps is to decode the image into a space which is pre-scaled to suit your purpose.  Here is a (probably too) simple [example](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto). (A better approach would restrict the scale factor to powers of 2.)

Comment: I'm already regarding these BitmapFacotry-options in my application. But now I need to crop (not scale) the existing Bitmap. And I don't get that done without causing an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score -1):

Hai please use this code

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sd);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ss);

    Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 180, 220, true);
    image.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
```

in this example the image "ss" will Scale or resized thing it helped you

Comment: I tried it, but createScaledBitmap scales the image. I want to crop it (cut a part out of the image). Anyway it doesn't solve the memory issues.