# How can I edit a photo taken via the camera in my application?

Tags: android, editor, photo

In my application I use the camera to take photos.
I use this code to start the camera Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
File file = new File(directory, timeStamp+".png"); //name 
Uri outputFileUri1 = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri1);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

This code is working, but how can I edit the preview image (crop, rotate,...) before my main Activity gets the data in `onActivityResult()`?
Or how can I start the photo editor for my image from my application?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String) object out of your image, then you could manipulate it.

```
String fooFile = "PATH TO FILE";
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fooFile);
```

here is a crop [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619032/how-to-crop-a-bitmap-with-a-minimum-usage-of-memory). for more examples just Google for 'Bitmap manipulation android'

Comment: Oh, no... Here's a sample algorithm of part of my application: 1)User start camera activity; 2)User press the button for shoot photo; 3)User confirms the photo (clicks "check") 4)program get data in onActivityResult, where create Bitmap object and load picture in ImageView. But I want between points "2)" and "3)" user can edit photo (for example, crop photo) and after confirmation main activity get cropped photo.

Comment: I'll need to implement your own camera activity, which will connect to the camera and handle the data according to users interactions